# Cancelling JQueryUI Resizable resize Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a simple `resizable` jQueryUI element.

```
element.resizable({
    start: function(event, ui) {...},
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        if(!shouldMove()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I thought that `return false` should cancel any jQuery action, however it resizes regardless of the response of `shouldMove()`. Is there a different way to cancel a jQuery resizable action? I've also tried `event.preventDefault();`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger mouseup event:

```
element.resizable({
    start: function(event, ui) {...},
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        if(!shouldMove()) {
            $(this).mouseup();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh that's clever. I'd never have thought of that! Also, you have an awesome surname.

Comment: This will still make it resize for one mousemove-event, and then disable it. So in effect it can still be resized if the user keeps regrabbing the resize-handler.

Answer (score 0):

Set original size to element each resize event:

```
element.resizable({
    start: function(event, ui) {...},
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        if(!shouldMove()) {
            ui.element.width(ui.originalSize.width);
            ui.element.height(ui.originalSize.height);
        }
    }
});
```